# Error in replacing inner html with javascript call

Tags: javascript, html

See code below.

Based on the option selected in the select box, I want to replace `innerHTML` of divs with `id=specific_dates_input` and `id=evt_date_input2`.

But no change takes place on the page and returns a null error.

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code?

```js
function addDates() {
  var occurance = document.getElementById("evt_occurance").value;

  if (occurance == 'daily') {
    alert("hi");
    document.getElementById("evt_date_txt").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("evt_date_input1").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("evt_date_txt2").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("evt_date_input2").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("specific_dates_btn").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("specific_dates_input").innerHTML = "";


  }
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="reg_lable">
    <label for="evt_occurance">Event Occurance:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select id="evt_occurance" name="occurance" onchange="addDates();">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="daily">Daily</option>

    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label id="evt_date_txt"></label>
  </td>
  <td id="evt_date_input1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label id="evt_date_txt2"></label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div id="evt_date_input2">hi</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="specific_dates_btn"></td>
  <td>
    <div id="specific_dates_input" class="bok">hiiii</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code? And what is the question you are asking? Also please indent your code to make it easy to read.

Comment: plz run code snippet and select daily option from select .i want to replace some txt when option is selected

Comment: Cause is - invalid HTML. Wrap your code in table tags, and it will work fine....

Comment: indent the code and fix the incorrect HTML syntax and you will see the problem.

Comment: i didnt get you sorry can u give the code as example mr ibu

Comment: Edited your question - check HTML. All works fine...

Comment: It is working fine, working exactly as programmed. Your code says to EMPTY out the DIVs when Daily is selected and that is exactly the code is doing. Instead of emptying if you want t put some text you would not say = "" you should put something inside "texthere".

Comment: @sinisake you should not make those syntactical changes to the OP's code, as that seems like it is the problem with the OP's code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine, if you will place all yours tr inside table tag.

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td class="reg_lable"><label for="evt_occurance">Event Occurance:</label></td>
   <td>
      <select id="evt_occurance" name="occurance" onchange="addDates();">
         <option>Select</option>
         <option value="daily">Daily</option>
      </select>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><label id="evt_date_txt"></label></td>
   <td id="evt_date_input1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><label id="evt_date_txt2"></label></td>
   <td>
      <div id="evt_date_input2">hi</div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td id="specific_dates_btn"></td>
   <td>
      <div id="specific_dates_input" class="bok">hiiii</div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><br></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

And your JS:

```
function addDates() {
  var occurance = document.getElementById("evt_occurance").value;

  if (occurance == 'daily') {
    alert("hi");
    document.getElementById("evt_date_txt").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("evt_date_input1").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("evt_date_txt2").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("evt_date_input2").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("specific_dates_btn").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("specific_dates_input").innerHTML = "";


  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your table rows / elements in the `<table>` tag and it will fix your errors, and your code will now also work correctly.

Table syntax as follows -

```
<table>
    <tr> <!-- Table Row -->
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```